# Убрать лишние места между margin

Tags: html, css, style, отступы

Как убрать лишнее место между отступами?

Вот скрин:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот между ними остается пустое место,как его убрать?синим выделены отступы картинок,как удалить пустое место между ними?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если у вас изображения отображаются, как inline-block, то это пробелы между ними. Вам просто нужно убрать текстовые ноды (пробелы тоже) в html между ними

Более подробно и о методах устранения можно прочитать здесь: [http://css-live.ru/articles/zagadochnye-otstupy-mezhdu-inlajn-blokami.html]

Answer (score 1):

Нужно сделать картинки блочными элементами и задать им `float:left` или `inline-block`

Comment: Спасибо,решил!!